# NoClassDefFoundError: CompanionConversion in scala activerecord

Tags: mysql, scala, activerecord

My goal is to connect with MySQL db and read/write to tables, however I keep getting the error in the run time (compile is fine):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/github/aselab/activerecord/inner/CompanionConversion

My code is like this:

build.sbt:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.aselab" %% "scala-activerecord" % "0.3.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.10", // other options are: slf4j-simple, logback-classic, etc...
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
)
```

./src/main/scala/Test.scala:

```
import com.github.aselab.activerecord._
import com.github.aselab.activerecord.dsl._
import dsl._

class Test {
  case class DateTest(var unix_timestamp: Long) extends ActiveRecord 
  object Tables extends ActiveRecordTables {
    val date_tests = table[DateTest]

  }   
  Tables.initialize(Map("schema" -> "tables.dev"))
  object DateTest extends ActiveRecordCompanion[DateTest]
  val a1 = DateTest.findBy("id" -> 1)
  println(s"field value: ${a1.get.unix_timestamp}")
```

./src/main/resources/application.conf:

```
tables {
  dev {
    driver = "some.Driver"
    jdbcurl = "some_url"
    username = "some_username"
    password = "some_password"
    partitionCount = 5 
    maxConnectionsPerPartition = 1 
    minConnectionsPerPartition = 5 
    autoCreate = false
    autoDrop = false
  }
  test {
    driver = "some.Driver"
    jdbcurl = "some:test"
    autoCreate = true
    autoDrop = true
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, model and schema definitions in inner class is not supported.
Probably, it will work with the following code:

src/main/scala/Test.scala

```
import com.github.aselab.activerecord._
import com.github.aselab.activerecord.dsl._

package models {
  case class DateTest(var unix_timestamp: Long) extends ActiveRecord
  object DateTest extends ActiveRecordCompanion[DateTest]

  object Tables extends ActiveRecordTables {
    val date_tests = table[DateTest]
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  import models._
  Tables.initialize(Map("schema" -> "tables.dev"))
  val a1 = DateTest.findBy("id" -> 1)
  println(s"field value: ${a1.get.unix_timestamp}")
  Tables.cleanup
}
```

src/main/resources/application.conf

```
models.Tables {
  dev {
    driver = "some.Driver"
    jdbcurl = "some_url"
    username = "some_username"
    password = "some_password"
    partitionCount = 5
    maxConnectionsPerPartition = 1
    minConnectionsPerPartition = 5
    autoCreate = false
    autoDrop = false
  }
  test {
    driver = "some.Driver"
    jdbcurl = "some:test"
    autoCreate = true
    autoDrop = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to put models into another folder: ./src/main/scala/models/DateTest.scala and put the package models {} code there, but the error is still the same..Looks like some of the classes is not found or linked? Could you help checking my dependencies in build.sbt to see if anything is missing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, I add the "extends App" this time, does it have anything to do with the CompanionConversion class? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks to me like you aren't including the jar for the scala-activerecord library in the runtime classpath. But, I do not know why to such behavior...